# CakePHP -> findall without has_many

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Model box

```
public $hasMany = array('Ticket' => array(
        'className' => 'Ticket',
        'order' => 'Ticket.created DESC',
        'foreign_key' => 'box_id'
    ));
```

Model Ticket

```
public $belongsTo = 'Box';
```

In BoxesController I get data from box table

```
$this->set('boxes', $this->Box->find('all'));
```

This function get all data from table Box and from table Ticket.
How can I get data only from one table, without join other tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->Box->recursive = -1;
$this->set('boxes', $this->Box->find('all'));
```

or

```
$this->Box->unbindModel(
        array('hasMany' => array('Ticket'))
   );
$this->set('boxes', $this->Box->find('all'));
```

[More on recursive](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive)

Comment: or use containable behavior and `'contain' => array()` or a default of -1 for recursive in all models via AppModel.